# restTemplate.exchange does not unmarshal complete object, but only top level - alternative to restTemplate?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, generics, kotlin, resttemplate

When I call my REST API using restTemplate.exchange, 
when the result is a simple array of objects,

```
...
ResponseEntity result = restTemplate.exchange(new URI(school.getUrl()) + reqMethod, HttpMethod.GET, entity, resultType);
return Arrays.asList((T[]) result.getBody());
...
```

everthing is OK.

BUT when the API returns a more complex object, like PageResult,

```
class PageResult<T>(var count: Long, var result: List<T>
```

then only the PageResult with its fields will be unmarshalled correctly, 
the  "result" itself returns as LinkedHashMap.

Suppose this is "works as designed", but I'd like to have the JSON completely in that Object,
as Spring Boot also does this on the bright, em, REST side of life :-)

Where's the knot in my head?

Comment: The rest template doesn't know about the embedded/generic type, hence it will use a map to put all the properties in. You can use the `ParameterizedType` to include this information. But simply using `PageResult` is basically setting `PageResult<Object>`. Something like `new ParameterizedType<PageResult<YourType>>()` should do the trick.

Comment: This exacly did the job, as @Trollsund wrote also in his answer. Thanks for the quick reply to both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are sending PageType::class.java to the exchange method. Like M. Deinum states in his comment, PageType::class.java does not know about the type of the elements in the result property, so the deserialiser won't know the type and defaults to LinkedHashMap.

To fix this, create a ParameterizedTypeReference and send it to the exchange method instead.

```
restTemplate.exchange(
    new URI(school.getUrl()) + reqMethod, 
    HttpMethod.GET, 
    entity,
    object : ParameterizedTypeReference<PageType<SomeClass>>() {})
```

Note that you can't just make a generic wrapper around this call, as that would yield the same result. If that's necessary, make the wrapper function inlined with reified type, kind of like this;

```
inline fun<T> foo(url: String, entity: HttpEntity) {
return restTemplate.exchange(
        url, 
        HttpMethod.GET, 
        entity,
        object : ParameterizedTypeReference<PageType<SomeClass>>() {})
}
```